# How to resolve Promise using async/await function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have try and catch once that is resolved my code is not reaching to last return `Promise.resolve(returnValue)` and throwing empty {} object , Any help will be appreciated to resolve below issue.

main.ts

```
private async combineData(data: any, request: any): Promise < any > {
    const details: any = [];
    const indexIDs = this.indexIDs;
    delete data.header.IndexOfRequestThatFailed;
    const returnValue = {
        "header": {
            "statusDesc": "",
            "statusCode": "",
            "refID": ""
        },
        "details": details
    }
    as IGetPaymentHistoryResponse;
    const paymentHistoryDetails = {
        header: returnValue.header,
        details: returnValue.details
    };
    // saving details to cache
    const saveDetails = {}
    as ICacheRequest;
    saveDetails.cacheobject = paymentHistoryDetails;
    saveDetails.cachetype = "CombinedPaymentHistoryCache";
    saveDetails.key =
    request.body.getPaymentHistoryRequest.header.serviceContext.tokenID;

    const _passedParams: ILogParams = {}
    as ILogParams;
    _passedParams.refId =
    request.body.getPaymentHistoryRequest.header.serviceContext.refID;
    _passedParams.sessionId =
    request.body.getPaymentHistoryRequest.header.serviceContext.tokenID;
    _passedParams.opname = "getPaymentHistory";
    _passedParams.starttime = moment().toString();
    _passedParams.endtime = "";

    try {
        await CacheController.getInstance().saveDetailsWrapper(saveDetails,
            _passedParams);
        return Promise.resolve({
            getPaymentHistoryResponse: paymentHistoryDetails
        });
    } catch (err) {

        return Promise.reject({
            getPaymentHistoryResponse: err
        });
    }
    return Promise.resolve(returnValue);

}
```

Comment: An async function returns a promise by default no? Do you really need to wrap your return in a promise?

Comment: Yeah just checked some examples, you should simply return the value or throw an error.

Comment: yes thats correct async returns promise but i tried just returning the object but it does not work i was trying to resolve it but my question is its not reaching to return statement

Comment: of course is not reaching last line, you are returning a promise in try and catch clauses, so it will never pass thought it. ps: you can return value itself when using async because it will wrap your response into a revolved promise, unless it throw an error, which will return a reject one.

Comment: try/catch is different operation just saving the data to cache it should not block rest of the code

Comment: so I assume you don't want to return a value inside your try clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `return` statement as `async` function returns Promise by default. So your returned value is equal to resolving a value, and throwing is rejection

```
try {
        await CacheController.getInstance().saveDetailsWrapper(saveDetails,
            _passedParams);
        return {
            getPaymentHistoryResponse: paymentHistoryDetails
        };
    } catch (err) {
        throw {
            getPaymentHistoryResponse: err
        };
    }
```

Code will not reach last line because there is a return statement in try and catch.

It is like you write

```
if(check) {... return 1}
else {return 2}
return 3
```

And ask why 3 is never returned

**Update**

I understood :) So async/await gives you ability to write asynchronous code in a sync way. If you want to make a request without blocking other code then just use plain `then`able syntax:

```
private combineData(data: any, request: any): any {
    const details: any = [];
    const indexIDs = this.indexIDs;
    delete data.header.IndexOfRequestThatFailed;
    const returnValue = {
        "header": {
            "statusDesc": "",
            "statusCode": "",
            "refID": ""
        },
        "details": details
    }
    as IGetPaymentHistoryResponse;
    const paymentHistoryDetails = {
        header: returnValue.header,
        details: returnValue.details
    };
    // saving details to cache
    const saveDetails = {}
    as ICacheRequest;
    saveDetails.cacheobject = paymentHistoryDetails;
    saveDetails.cachetype = "CombinedPaymentHistoryCache";
    saveDetails.key =
    request.body.getPaymentHistoryRequest.header.serviceContext.tokenID;

    const _passedParams: ILogParams = {}
    as ILogParams;
    _passedParams.refId =
    request.body.getPaymentHistoryRequest.header.serviceContext.refID;
    _passedParams.sessionId =
    request.body.getPaymentHistoryRequest.header.serviceContext.tokenID;
    _passedParams.opname = "getPaymentHistory";
    _passedParams.starttime = moment().toString();
    _passedParams.endtime = "";

    // do not return here to return on the last line
    CacheController.getInstance().saveDetailsWrapper(saveDetails, _passedParams).then(response => ..., err => ...);
    return returnValue;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what would be approach if i also want to return returnValue

Comment: @hussain, oh, wait, what is the case when to return the data that is on the last line?

Comment: @hussain you want to return `returnValue` if `saveDetailsWrapper` rejected? or when?

Comment: In both cases returnValue should return

Comment: Error: Type 'IGetPaymentHistoryResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, [Symb

Comment: @hussain, can I see your `IGetPaymentHistoryResponse` interface? add it to the question please

Comment: And also the usage of `combineData` method. how it is used